# Specify a hg dependency in tox.ini

Tags: python, mercurial, tox

What's the correct way to specify a hg dependency in `tox.ini`. e.g.

```
[testenv]
deps =
    hg+https://code.google.com/p/python-progressbar/
```

Unfortunately this does not work, and the following is spewed out:

```
ERROR: invocation failed, logfile: /Users/brad/project/.tox/py33-dj/log/py33-dj-1.log
ERROR: actionid=py33-dj
msg=getenv
cmdargs=[local('/Users/brad/project/.tox/py33-dj/bin/pip'), 'install', '--download-cache=/Users/brad/.pip/downloads', 'hg+https://code.google.com/p/python-progressbar/', 'https://github.com/dag/attest/tarball/master', 'django-attest', 'django-celery', 'coverage', 'https://github.com/django/django/tarball/master']
env={'PYTHONIOENCODING': 'utf_8', 'TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION': '309', 'LOGNAME': 'brad', 'USER': 'brad', 'PATH': '/Users/brad/project/.tox/py33-dj/bin:/usr/local/share/python:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/texbin', 'HOME': '/Users/brad', 'DISPLAY': '/tmp/launch-zayh2U/org.macosforge.xquartz:0', 'TERM_PROGRAM': 'Apple_Terminal', 'LANG': 'en_AU.UTF-8', 'TERM': 'xterm-256color', 'SHLVL': '1', '_': '/usr/local/share/python/tox', 'TERM_SESSION_ID': 'E8FC4113-C18B-4DB4-9594-C0909A132D76', 'SSH_AUTH_SOCK': '/tmp/launch-kia8RP/Listeners', 'SHELL': '/bin/bash', 'TMPDIR': '/var/folders/zr/m_ys6vwd1z19rqh73jd8z88w0000gn/T/', '__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING': '0x1F5:0:15', 'PWD': '/Users/brad/project', 'PIP_DOWNLOAD_CACHE': '/Users/brad/.pip/downloads', 'COMMAND_MODE': 'unix2003'}
abort: couldn't find mercurial libraries in [/usr/local/Cellar/mercurial/2.4.1/libexec /Users/brad/project/.tox/py33-dj/lib/python3.3/site-packages/distribute-0.6.31-py3.3.egg /Users/brad/project/.tox/py33-dj/lib/python3.3/site-packages/pip-1.2.1-py3.3.egg /Users/brad/project/.tox/py33-dj/lib/python33.zip /Users/brad/project/.tox/py33-dj/lib/python3.3 /Users/brad/project/.tox/py33-dj/lib/python3.3/plat-darwin /Users/brad/project/.tox/py33-dj/lib/python3.3/lib-dynload /usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.3.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3 /usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.3.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/plat-darwin /Users/brad/project/.tox/py33-dj/lib/python3.3/site-packages]
(check your install and PYTHONPATH)
Downloading/unpacking hg+https://code.google.com/p/python-progressbar/
  Cloning hg https://code.google.com/p/python-progressbar/ to /var/folders/zr/m_ys6vwd1z19rqh73jd8z88w0000gn/T/pip-88u_g0-build
  Complete output from command /usr/local/bin/hg clone --noupdate -q https://code.google.com/p/python-progressbar/ /var/folders/zr/m_ys6vwd1z19rqh73jd8z88w0000gn/T/pip-88u_g0-build:

----------------------------------------
Command /usr/local/bin/hg clone --noupdate -q https://code.google.com/p/python-progressbar/ /var/folders/zr/m_ys6vwd1z19rqh73jd8z88w0000gn/T/pip-88u_g0-build failed with error code 255 in None
Storing complete log in /Users/brad/.pip/pip.log

ERROR: could not install deps [hg+https://code.google.com/p/python-progressbar/]
_________________________________________ summary _________________________________________
ERROR:   py33-dj: could not install deps [hg+https://code.google.com/p/python-progressbar/]
```

The last line in `pip.log` is:

```
pip.exceptions.InstallationError: Command /usr/local/bin/hg clone --noupdate -q https://code.google.com/p/python-progressbar/ /var/folders/zr/m_ys6vwd1z19rqh73jd8z88w0000gn/T/pip-dakkvs-build failed with error code 255 in None
```

However running `pip install hg+https://code.google.com/p/python-progressbar/` works.

The tox test environment is targeting Python 3.3.

Answer (score 6):

It's possible to specify the mercurial dependency in two ways within `deps = …`:

- `-ehg+https://code.google.com/p/python-progressbar/#egg=progressbar` (no space)
- `hg+https://code.google.com/p/python-progressbar/`

tox treats each line in `deps` as a single argument to `pip install` (whitespace included).

pip supports `-e` as either a standalone argument followed by a URL, or the prefix of a single argument, i.e.:

- `['pip', 'install', '-e', 'hg+https://...']`
- `['pip', 'install', '-ehg+https://...']`

but will not handle `['pip', 'install', '-e hg+https://...']` (because the URL is parsed to include a space character)

## So why didn't it work?

Mercurial was installed under Python 2.7. When tox runs `pip install`, it sets the `PATH` env variable to refer to the Python 3.3 env it created. If you look carefully through the error message you'll see the line:

```
abort: couldn't find mercurial libraries in …
```

which is printed by the `/usr/local/bin/hg` script when `import mercurial` fails. Typically the solution would be to install the library (mercurial) for Python 3.3. Unfortunately mercurial does not support Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

typically this is a artifact of a broken mercurial installation that refers to env python

in virtualenv for python 3 the env python is simply the worst thing to work with